# How to make a field required based on another field in FSH (FHIR Shorthand) language?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am defining a profile in DetectedIssue resource and want to make mitigation field as required when the status field of this resource = final. Can someone help me how to do that? Here is the profile definition of my DetectedIssue resource.

```
Profile: SystemPatientDetectedIssue
Parent: DetectedIssue
Id: patient-detectedissue
Title: "Patient Alert DetectedIssue"
Description: "Profile of DetectedIssue for capturing patient alerts"

* status from SystemDetectedIssueStatusValueSet (required)
* code 1..1
* code from SystemDetectedIssueCodeValueSet (required)
* patient 1..1
* identifiedDateTime 1..1
* detail 1..1
* author 1..1
* author.identifier 1..1
* author.identifier.type from SystemIdentifierValueSet (required)

// Mitigation required when marking the issue as "final".
// How to Make the mitigation field required when setting the issue as final?
* mitigation 0..1
* mitigation.action.coding from SystemDetectedIssueMitigationActionValueSet
* mitigation.action.text 1..1
* mitigation.date 1..1
* mitigation.author 1..1
```

And here is the valueset definition (SystemDetectedIssueStatusValueSet) for status attribute above:

```
Alias: OBSERVATION_STATUS = http://hl7.org/fhir/observation-status

ValueSet: SystemDetectedIssueStatusValueSet
Id: system-detected-issue-status-value-set
Title: "System DetectedIssue status ValueSet"
* ^url = https://terminology.system.com/ValueSet/detectedissue-status
* include OBSERVATION_STATUS#registered
* include OBSERVATION_STATUS#cancelled
* include OBSERVATION_STATUS#final
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any constraints that depend on relationships between elements (like `status` and `mitigation`) can only be constrained using an invariant.  Invariants are set on [ElementDefinition.constraint](http://hl7.org/fhir/R4/elementdefinition-definitions.html#ElementDefinition.constraint) in FHIR, but FSH has a special mechanism for invariants [documented here](http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/fhir-shorthand/reference.html#defining-invariants).  The most difficult thing about invariants is that they use another language, called FHIRPath, to express the constraint.  You should look at the [core FHIRPath](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/) documentation as well as the [FHIR-specific FHIRPath documentation](http://hl7.org/fhir/R4/fhirpath.html).

For your specific example, you would first define your invariant as a separate item.  The special FHIRPath expression is in the Expression field:

```
Invariant:   final-mitigation
Description: "If DetectedIssue.status is final, then DetectedIssue.mitigation must be present"
Expression:  "status = 'final' implies mitigation.exists()"
Severity:    #error
```

Then, since it talks about two elements, relative to the root of the resource, you add a top-level obeys rule to your profile that brings in the invariant you just created:

```
* obeys final-mitigation
```

In the future, you'll probably have the best luck asking these questions in the [#shorthand](https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/215610-shorthand) stream of chat.fhir.org, where there is a whole community of people that can help.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and will make sure to ask questions in chat from next time.

Comment: You’re welcome!